# CSS no funciona tras usar una Redirección URL

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una web y me funcionan bien los CSS, pero a la hora de usar una redirección de URL (Pasar de https://misitio.com/pagina.php?Variable=0 a https://misitio.com/promocion/nombre ) al pasar a /promocion/nombre no me carga bien los CSS.

lo he intentado de las siguientes formas:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://misitio.com/css/style.css">
```

ninguna de las formas me carga el CSS, me sale solo la pagina pero en blanco, todo lo que es el HTML no me carga, el cambio si borro la entrada del css me carga el HTML pero sin los formatos. No tengo ni idea de como hacer para que me corra bien.

Adjunto imagenes de donde tengo el directorio con respecto a la raiz y como tengo los demás archivos css.

Esta es la carpeta raiz.

[image: Imagen1]

esta es la carpeta CSS.

[image: Imagen2]

Este es el codigo fuente de como lo tengo.

[image: Imagen 3]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner en tu pregunta una imagen de cómo tienes tus directorios, por favor? Probablemente no estás usando bien tus rutas relativas, ya que depende en qué parte esté tu `style.css` en referencia a tu posición actual (promocion/nombre).

Comment: Clic derecho > Ver código fuente. Asegúrate que son las rutas correctas.

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta con imágenes de lo que me solicitas.

Comment: Si pones tu dominio real lo puedo ver... Será más fácil que asumir cosas...

Comment: http://neofilo.ddns.net/promocion/Villa-Daganzo-64 @OCHOA

Comment: @ochoa gracias por la ayuda, ya lo solucioné. responderé mi propia pregunta.

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner la url completa en los ficheros de css?
Por ejemplo: https://misitio.com/css/style.css
En lugar de: /css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no radicaba en los CSS si no en los Javascript que estaban mal direccionados.